# Software to draw static infographics for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, drawing

I would like to create static infographics and I am looking for a piece of software that aims to do this, is open-source (or at least free of charge), works on Linux and runs locally on my desktop (thus, no web application).

I have already checked [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=infographics) for relevant matches, but I could not spot anything matching the specs of this query.

Comment: It is unclear what `static infographics` are and how they differ from any other vector graphic

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) would be a decent fit for this, or at least for static infographics. If you want to do anything more advanced, such as [animated infographics](https://www.atlassian.com/information-management-infographic) then you may have to look into something else, perhaps [animated SVG](https://davidwalsh.name/svg-animation). What output (file format) are you looking for?

Comment: Static infographics (title and content edited accordingly). I could show these infographics in my computer screen or project them with a beamer or mail them or perhaps include them in a website.